# \newtcbtheorem blanking beginning of the paragraph

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, theorems

I am using the packge `\newtcbtheorem` on beamer. For some reason, the first letter of the paragraph is blancking. Any idea of what is happening?

```
\documentclass[xcolor,10pt]{beamer} 

\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

%%%Environments
\newtcbtheorem{mydef}{Definition}%
{colback=white,
colframe=red!35!white,
enhanced,
  sharp corners,
fonttitle=\bfseries
}{th}


\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Definitions and notation}
\begin{mydef}{Teste}
The first letter, which is T. is missing.
\end{mydef}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `mydef` environment has two arguments: the title and the label for later `\ref`. `\begin{mydef}{Teste}{}` will do

Comment: Ah... I am sorry I have missed this. Thank you so much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it‘s solved by comments.